# Detect when home button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I need to hide a UIImageView when the user presses the home button. I tried using pressesBegan(_:with:) but is was never calling. Does anyone know how to detect when the home Button is pressed?

```
@IBOutlet weak var shouldHideView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
}

func hide(){
    self.shouldHideView.isHidden = true
}

override fun pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?){ 
    self.hide()
}
```

Comment: Please give us more of your code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: complete code is missing here

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, the tool you want for this is `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationWillResignActive(_:)`. This is called a bit more frequently than when the home button is pressed, but generally it's what you actually mean. (There is no call made *only* when the home button is pressed.)

Comment: That is only called when the app will resign activity. But im my case i need something that is called as soon as the user presses the home button. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: There is nothing in iOS that is called exclusively when the user presses the home button. If you want to protect sensitive data on the screen, you use either willResignActive or didEnterBackground. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html (Being a Responsible Background App, Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background) for Apple's guidance on this problem.

Comment: "Resign active" happens in a few cases that "will enter background" does not (such as when there's an incoming call, but then you go right back to the app), so the question is what you want to do in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the home button press event is not available on the iOS SDK. You could use any of the following UIApplicationDelegate methods to observe when the application goes to the background:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Tells the delegate that the app is now in the background.
}
```